# Installing Pdftk on Linux server

Tags: php, linux, pdftk

Ihave been using pdftk.exe in my windows local machine to play with some pdf and is working fine. I want to upload it to my server which is Linux. On searching i found out that i have to install pdftk on the server itself as a compiled package for Red Hat. How can i do this ?? can anyone help me on this??

Answer (score 1):

pdftk is not a special case for rpm or any other distro's package system.  rpm -i the .rpm.